# AWS EMR spark job step won't execute

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a spark program on aws. It simple reads the csv file and prints it with dataframe.show(). I have been waiting for the step to execute since past 15-20 mins but no progress. The csv file inside the s3 bucket is very small only 10 rows of 2 columns.
Here is my program:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object TriangleCountMain {
    //Edge object
    case class Edge(from: Int, to: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val logger: org.apache.log4j.Logger = LogManager.getRootLogger
        if (args.length != 2) {
          logger.error("Usage:\nTwitterDataSet_Spark.TriangleCountMain <input dir> <output dir>")
          System.exit(1)
        }

    //Spark Session
    val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
    .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    //Dataframe structure
    val dfSchema = StructType(Array(
        StructField("from", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("to", IntegerType, true)))


    //Data set of edges
    val nonFilteredEdge: Dataset[Edge] = spark.read
                        .option("header", "false")
                        .option("inferSchema", "true")
                        .schema(dfSchema)
                        .csv(args(0))
                        .as[Edge]


    val edge = nonFilteredEdge
    edge.show
    spark.stop
  }
}
```

This programs runs on local successfully. 
Thank you.

Comment: Where are you providing the login info for S3 like: aws_access_key_id={YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
aws_secret_access_key={YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} ? and  are you using the right path to access S3 bucket?

Comment: Could you provide the log output from EMR?